# Is this approach acceptable instead of $watch when passing service variables to controller?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do angular the right way and see people wanting to avoid using $watch. I've been using this method but haven't seen anyone do it recommended in my searches.

```
angular
 .module
 .service('ServiceEx', function(){
   this.exampleValue = "Hello";
   this.getHello = function(){
    return this.exampleValue
   }
 }

//in controller
$scope.exampleFromService = ServiceEx.getHello();
```

I know this is super basic example so it is unneeded in this circumstance, but I started doing this when I was running into the issue of the service variable getting changed and my scope not updating with the new value.

Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: I don't think so; I tend to do something very similair. Usually I will set var service = this; and then any functions that should be public get set to a property of the service variable.

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Making a service call and saving the result to an object on the scope is a pretty common occurrance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's completely acceptable, you should always use this approach instead of $watch or $rootScope. Services are definitely the best practice in this case. An just for completion:

```
angular.module("app", []).service('ServiceEx', function(){
  this.exampleValue = "Hello";

  this.setHello = function(hello){
     this.exampleValue = hello;
  }

  this.getHello = function(){
    return this.exampleValue
  }
}

//in controller
ServiceEx.setHello("Hello2");
$scope.exampleFromService = ServiceEx.getHello();
```

Comment: What advantages does ServiceEx.setHello('Hello2') have over just doing ServiceEx.exampleValue = "hello"? I am not doubting you, just wondering so I understand it right.

Comment: So you can change the value of the variable whenever you wants, for example: maybe now you want to add the name of the user. So when he clicks the log in buton for example you set the the variable to ServiceEx.setHello('Hello User').